# Testing RESTful service, should I also check the data layer?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, tdd, integration-testing

Testing the results of the endpoints is straight forward.

However, shouldn't I also have a look at the db layer, if (i.e.) the data I POSTed is saved correctly? I'm unclear how/if the business logic behind the REST call should be tested.

Answer (score 1):

In my perfect world (someday I'd like to live there...) there are several different tests involved in fully validating a RESTful service I am providing.

There are *unit tests* for each of the logical layers of the application, that use dependency injection to mock the next lower layer and validate that each unit works correctly.  This might be a unit that marshals/unmarshals the parameters and response, a unit that executes business logic, and a unit that manages persistence.  (There could be multiple units, each with their own tests at each layer.)  These tests have no dependencies outside the testing framework, with the exception of the persistence layer which has to exercise your persistence implementation.

There are also *integration tests* that require a running system. This is where you call the running service, and verify that you got the expected response.  You may also inspect side effects of the call. On my team, we often do that by making a different service call (or calls) that relies on the result of the first call.  That exercises more of the system. We find that direct inspection of the persistence layer for side effects seldom tells us much that we can't get by using a different service call.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should test the db layer at some point but probably not in the same unit test than the one that test the result of the endpoint.

At the Unit Test level you would like to have small/quick/independant tests so you might end up with a test/suite for the REST part and another one focussing on db layer.
Then you might have some more integration/end-to-end tests that check the whole system : doing the request and checking the db is correctly updated.

My own experience, working as a QA, is that the tests involving DB are done with integration/end-to-end tests with a functional perspective  by the QA using a third-party tool (we use [Robot Framework](http://robotframework.org/) for that).

Comment: Isn't a REST call a "end-to-end" test in the truest sense?

Comment: sure. I was using it with a tester perspective trying to convey the idea that for such test we won't just check the JSON returned by the server but also expected outcome in other part of the system (like "a user was added in this table of that db")

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is use the restful service itself to test that the data correctly persisted,

For example you can use the PUT message to persist an entity and use the GET operation to retrieve it, and make sure all properties are equal. This is more of an integration test which covers end to end.

Especially your application is doing more CRUD operations, and if you use this approach you could avoid creating tests for each and every layer (such as repositories)